# How can i set @media only screen less then 320px for indetificator?

Tags: css, mobile, responsibility

I have this piece of code. I'm  beginner :/

https://ibb.co/ccrFFG
Id like to add some responsibility by 
`@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}`
but it doesnt works with IDs. How would you change the code pls? :)

Thanks

Comment: Please do not add code as image instead paste your code here.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but I will advise you to use the code below as a guide.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #yourID {
        width: 260px !important;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

css media-querys only work if you use the viewport meta-tag, make sure that you use it on your site.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can ready more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag